# Active perl Mechanize bad request error

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to get https using Mechanize but failed with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::SSL;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->proxy(['https','http'], 'http://proxy:8080/');
$mech->get('https://www.google.com');

print $mech->content;
```

Error:

```
Error GETing https://www.google.com: Bad Request at perl4.pl line 9.
```

When I try to use `LWP::UserAgent` I am able to get https without any error:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->proxy(['https','http'], 'http://proxy:8080/');
$ua->get('https://www.google.com');
```

Can anyone help out with this?

Currently using Mechanize 1.72

Comment: Works for me (without proxy). Ask the system admin that is responsible for the proxy to assist you in debugging.

Comment: I have tried to use the same proxy in the code for User Agent and I could get the https without any bad request error. 

So I thought there is something wrong with my code not the proxy. Could you explain why does a proxy works with one library but not other? Especially in this case where Mechanize is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent, I guess the get method in Mechanize is the same as UserAgent get method. Sorry for the noob question. This is the first time I am working on proxy and perl.

Comment: Works for me (with proxy). One reason could be that the proxy denies requests if the User-Agent header matches WWW-Mechanize.

Comment: Vaguely remembered something on perlmonks. Either of these look applicable? http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=643830  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=896895

Comment: I have tried to debug and got the below message:
http://pastebin.com/sNxqfD20
In the WWW::Mechanize::request debug logs it looks like it is getting a http request instead of https.

Comment: I have just found the the LWP::UserAgent code is also returning Bad request error. And have just found a bug report on LWP [link](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=1894)

Anyone is able to connect to https site via proxy server using User Agent or Mechanize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed LWP-Protocol-connect-6.03
and connect to the proxy with

```
$https_proxy = 'connect://proxy:8080/';
```

It is working fine now :D

Answer (score 4):

WWWW::Mechanize is based on LWP::UserAgent, which for years has a strange idea of https proxy requests, e.g. instead of using a CONNECT request to build a tunnel and then upgrade to SSL it sends a GET request with a https-URL.
See https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=1894

A fix is finally merged into libwwww-perl github repository, but I don't know when a new version of LWP will be released. In the meantime you might use Net::SSLGlue::LWP which monkey patches LWP to provide proper support for https proxy (I'm the author of Net::SSLGlue::LWP and of the fixes to LWP).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, based on the error you provided that your proxy is blocking a certain User-Agent. The HTTP user agent used by LWP::UserAgent is different from that of WWW::Mechanize.

I suggest to try to use this line:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36' );
```

This will make the proxy, and the receiving server to believe you are a Chrome browser, rather than some sort of crawler/malware/virus/etc

Another suggestion is to to do a data dumper on the $mech element and confirm what is "inside":

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($mech);
```

You can also use this same method to dump the content of `$mech` after the `get()` function call.

Not sure it is relevant but note, not all Proxies support HTTPS/SSL, only those that allow inline proxying/CONNECT proxying will allow you to proxy HTTPS/SSL traffic.